# using mem.eql - unable to evaluate constant expression

Tags: zig

Can someone explain me why [this piece of code](https://zig.godbolt.org/z/reK6xv7h5) can't be compiled?

```
const std = @import("std");

const ParseError = error { NotAValidField };

const TestEnum = enum {
    field_1,
    field_2,

    pub fn fromString(str: []const u8) !TestEnum {
        switch(true) {
            std.mem.eql(u8, "field_1", str) => TestEnum.field_1,
            std.mem.eql(u8, "field_2", str) => TestEnum.field_2,
            else => ParseError.NotAValidField,
        }
    }
};

pub fn main() void {
    const field = "field_1";
    try TestEnum.fromString(field);
}
```

It results to an error:

```
./example.zig:11:40: error: unable to evaluate constant expression
            std.mem.eql(u8, "field_1", str) => TestEnum.field_1,
```

Is the compiler trying to figure the `str` during the compile time while it is passed as an argument? Here's the code in godbolt: https://zig.godbolt.org/z/reK6xv7h5

P.S. I already know there is a `std.meta.stringToEnum` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler sees `str` in `mem.eql` call as a runtime value, and thus the error.  To specify that `str` is never used at run time, add a `comptime` keyword like so:

```
pub fn fromString(comptime str: []const u8) TestEnum {
    return switch (true) {
        std.mem.eql(u8, "field_1", str) => TestEnum.field_1,
        std.mem.eql(u8, "field_2", str) => TestEnum.field_2,
    };
}
```

Note that all of this comes from wanting to use the `mem.eql` results to match `true`.  This limits the number of enum values to exactly two and requires the string to be known at compile time.  What `meta.stringToEnum` does instead is to perform the operation at run time.